# In vscode, how do I report a performance issue if I cannot open the help menu?

Tags: performance, github, visual-studio-code

I recently filed an issue with vscode on linux.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122019

When I start vscode, the application pegs the cpu and refuses to react to user interaction. The issue was summarily closed with a reference to:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues

The instructions on that page suggest that

"To report a performance issue please use the 'Report Issue' command available in the 'Help' menu."

The only trouble is that I cannot open the 'Help' menu, for obvious reasons.

What should I do?

To answer peoples' questions. The logs are empty:

```
$ cat .config/Code/logs/20210424T091049/output_1_20210424T091050/*
$
```

And I get the same result running

```
$ code --disable-extensions --disable-gpu
```

Comment: anything in the logs? ~/.config/Code/logs.

Comment: have you tried starting `code` with various command line options like `disable hardware acceleration`, `disable extensions`. Which thread of VSC is consuming the CPU? Have you read the wiki page about Performance Issues